# how to send https request from lua in haproxy before routing request?

Tags: lua, haproxy, haproxy-ingress

I used haproxy Socket class as outlined here https://www.haproxy.com/blog/5-ways-to-extend-haproxy-with-lua/#actions to make **http** request to external service from lua code (See code below).

1. How can I make an **https** request to the service?
2. Is it possible to specify a domain name instead of IP address of the service to connect to?

Any help is appreciated.

```
local function http_request(txn, data)
    local addr = <external-IP>
    local port = 80

    -- Set up a request to the service
    local hdrs = {
        [1] = string.format('host: %s:%s', addr, port),
        [2] = 'accept: */*',
        [3] = 'connection: close'
    }
    
    local req = {
        [1] = string.format('GET %s HTTP/1.1', data.path),
        [2] = table.concat(hdrs, '\r\n'),
        [3] = '\r\n'
    }

    req = table.concat(req,  '\r\n')

    -- Use core.tcp to get an instance of the Socket class
    local socket = core.tcp()
    socket:settimeout(data.timeout)

    -- Connect to the service and send the request
    if socket:connect(addr, port) then
        if socket:send(req) then
            -- Skip response headers
            while true do
                local line, _ = socket:receive('*l')

                if not line then break end
                if line == '' then break end
            end

            -- Get response body, if any
            local content = socket:receive('*a')
            return content

        else
            core.Alert('Could not connect to server (send)')
        end

        socket:close()
    else
        core.Alert('Could not connect to server (connect)')
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently while working on a problem I figured out that we cannot pass domain name. I was using [http.lua](https://github.com/haproxytech/haproxy-lua-http/blob/master/http.lua) lib. This http.lua lib uses Socket class as you are doing in your code.

Also after searching a lot I was unable to find a dns resolver lib. One was there something related to nginx lua, but it requires installing lots of different lua libs, so I skipped it.

The work around I did is, created my own dns resolver service http://127.0.0.1:53535 in HAProxy as below

```
listen lua_dns
    bind 127.0.0.1:53535

    http-request do-resolve(txn.dstip,mydns,ipv4) hdr(ResolveHost),lower
    http-request return status 200 content-type text/plain lf-string OK hdr ResolvedIp "%[var(txn.dstip)]"
```

To this service I pass the domain name in request header `ResolveHost` and get the IP in response header `ResolvedIp`.

Now the lua functions to parse the domain from URL and call dns resolver service is as below

```
local function parse_domain(url)

    local schema, host, _ = url:match("^(.*)://(.-)[?/](.*)$")

    if not schema then
        -- maybe path (request uri) is missing
        schema, host = url:match("^(.*)://(.-)$")
        if not schema then
            core.Info("ERROR :: Could not parse URL: "..url)
            return nil
        end
    end

    return host

end

local function resolve_domain(domain)

    local d = parse_domain(domain)    
    
    local r, msg = http.get{ url = "http://127.0.0.1:53535", headers={ResolveHost=d} }
    if r == nil then
        core.Info("ERROR: "..msg..". While resolving doamin: "..d)
        return msg
    end

    return r.headers['resolvedip']

end
```

Now replace the resolved IP with the domain name in the URL using gsub()

`url = string:gsub(domain_name, resolved_ip)`

and then call your API using http.lua

`local res, msg = http.get{ url=url, headers=headers }`

Here the http.lua lib will handle HTTP and HTTPS urls.